# Train NGramModel in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk, n-gram

I am using Python 3.5, installed and managed with Anaconda. I want to train an NGramModel (from nltk) using some text. My installation does not find the module nltk.model

There are some possible answers to this question (pick the correct one, and explain how to do it):

1. A different version of nltk can be installed using conda, so that it contains the model module. This is not just an older version (it would need to be too old), but a different version containing the model (or model2) branch of the current nltk development.
2. The version of nltk mentioned in the previous point cannot be installed using conda, but can be installed using pip.
3. nltk.model is deprecated, better use some other package (explain which package)
4. there are better options than nltk for training an ngram model, use some other library (explain which library)
5. none of the above, to train an ngram model the best option is something else (explain what).

Comment: For pure language models, i would recommend [KenLM](https://kheafield.com/code/kenlm/) which is highly opimised (in C for both speed and memory). It is also used in [moses](http://www.statmt.org/moses/index.php?n=Main.HomePage), the most used MT tool which also has some good [KenLM instructions](http://www.statmt.org/moses/?n=FactoredTraining.BuildingLanguageModel#ntoc20).

Comment: The module `ntk.model` [doesn't exist](http://www.nltk.org/py-modindex.html) in the newest version of NLTK ([3.2.1](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nltk)). By using Anaconda you install version [3.2.0](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/pkg-docs), which hasn't also the module.

Comment: @Darius correct, the version at the `model` branch should be installed to use `nltk.model`.

Comment: @Darius nevertheless, that would most probably be pointless, because the code there is different from previous versions. Therefore: (1) all examples online are useless. And (2) the code to perform the training of an ngram model (and pretty much everything) is not in that branch (even if the `model` package is), AFAIK.

Comment: @schwobaseggl thank you, I have also found [other tools](http://www.cstr.ed.ac.uk/projects/speech_tools/manual-1.2.0/x2759.htm) that may serve for the purpose suitably. I was hoping for something simple and straightforward inside python, since I'm using pandas and a number of things for some operations before and after the ngrams part. I may call KenLM as an external program.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
import nltk
nltk.download('all')
```

in your notebook